# How to connect to mssql server using polars.write_database?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, python-polars

I have a connection object `sql_conn` like this

```
CNXN_STR = 'DRIVER={ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server};SERVER=aws-dev...;DATABASE=DB;MARS_Connection=no;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=user;PWD=pass@1'
sql_conn = sqlalchemy_connect(CNXN_STR)

def sqlalchemy_connect(connection_string):
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={quoted}', fast_executemany=True)
    conn = engine.connect()
    return conn
```

This `sql_conn` object worked well when working with pandas and to upload data to my DB, I can simply do `df.to_sql(table_name, sql_conn, if_exists='append')`.

But now I am trying to migrate to polars and I'm trying to use [polars.write_database()](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_database.html#polars.DataFrame.write_database) method:

```
df.write_database(table_name, sql_conn, if_table_exists='append')
```

But I am getting error  `Failed saving to table due to 'Connection' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'`

Does anyone know why? Please help

Comment: could you try `conn = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=??;Database=??;Trusted_Connection=yes;"` and then just `.read_database(<query>, conn)`?

Comment: you mean write_database?

Comment: `.write_database()` expects connection to be a string `connection: str` - it calls `create_engine` internally: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/polars/dataframe/frame.py#L3685 - the lack of type checking in this case is probably considered a "bug".

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer, polars.write_datbase() expects a connection URI and not a connection object or engine. I had to create a connection URI that followed this format along with the driver which worked:

```
'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pass}@{server}/{DB}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
```